# Batch stuff up,windows xp text size

Tags: batch-file

I accidentily was playing around with some code at school and then I ran a code, now everything is stuffed up. HELP. (running windows xp btw)

here is the code

```
@echo off
::turn off wallpaper
SET KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"
REG ADD %KEY% /V Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "(None)" /f

::Windows classic theme
set KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsof…
REG ADD %KEY% /v ThemeActive /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f

::massive size
SET KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics"
REG ADD %KEY% /v AppliedDPI /t REG_DWORD /d "0x120" /f

SET KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse"
REG ADD %KEY% /v SwapMouseButtons /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f
shutdown -r
exit
```

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by, "stuffed up"? Screenshot, possibly?

Comment: Like the text on the task bar is too small to read! Sorry on the school computer i cannot take screen shots... oh and if possable include code to undo this since I cant access controll panel

Comment: School Goal Achieved! --- Lessons learned: (1) never "play around" code you don't know (2) never change Registry without a backup.

Comment: Hahaha yeah your prob right!! :P

Comment: for 1 thing you can press Window-key+R to get the RUN box then type in "control" it should open. another thing tell the "school" to look into DEEP FREEZE it is a software basically it gives the computer a permanent base to start from if you change the registry it will reset it after a restart deep freeze can enabled or disabled by the administrator of the machine (NOT THE USER PROFILE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics"
REG ADD %KEY% /v AppliedDPI /t REG_DWORD /d "0x96" /f
```